# How to select speakers for iTunes from applescript

Tags: applescript, itunes

I would like to be able to select output sound device for iTunes from a script (any programming language would be ok in fact).

For the moment I was able to use UI element scripting to get up to clicking on the button which gives the menu to select the speakers:

```js
tell application "System Events"
     tell window "iTunes" of process "iTunes"
        set chbtn to first UI element whose help is "Choose which speakers to use."
        tell chbtn
            click
            -- tell menu 1 to get every menu item
        end tell
     end tell
end tell
```

This works, and menu with possible choices appears.  However, the applescript seems to stop after the **click** command, and further actions (in the place where the comment is in the code) happen only after I click somewhere on the screen myself.  How can I prevent this and continue to select the menu item from this menu?

Any solution without reverting to UI scripting is also very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The solution code is

```applescript
tell application "iTunes" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell window "iTunes" of process "iTunes"
        click (first UI element whose help is "Choose which speakers to use.")
        keystroke "DENON" & return -- Select "DENON" airplay entry
        -- keystroke "Computer" & return -- Select standard output
     end tell
end tell
```

However, there is an annoying 4 second delay between the `click` and the `keystroke`

Answer (score 0):

I've had that delay problem before when using UI scripting. You might be able to eliminate it by telling the script which elements to click. I don't have external speakers, so the elements' names and properties aren't on my computer. An easy way to get more info on the elements available is to use (not free, but excellent) UI Browser http://pfiddlesoft.com/uibrowser/. A less easy, but free, way to get more info on the elements is to use:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell window "iTunes" of process "iTunes"
        set chbtn to first UI element whose help is "Show or hide item artwork and video viewer."
        tell chbtn
            entire contents
        end tell
end tell
```

end tell

Comment: Thank you, a very nice hint with 'entire contents'.  But that does not help too much -- the list is empty.  The menu seems to appear only after the click happens.  In the other time it is absent.  Somehow, even when it is present I was unable to find, where the menu belongs to (it is not even in entire contents of the process "iTunes").  Moreover, the delay happens immediately after the click on the button, independent on what the next command is.