# How to control a non-applescript application?

Tags: macos, applescript, playlist

I am developing an osx app that displays a live feed of what is playing in Traktor Pro(DJ Software), traktor uses .nml files for its track history/playlist which i will then parse. The file contains the history(track, artist, length etc. ) of the current set.

The problem is that Traktor only saves the file when it shuts down or when the user saves the track-list in a .nml file. As traktor does not support apple-script i dont know how to automate the export.

The file would have to save/update around every 1-2 minutes.

Here is the action that has to be automated in the background

Application layout:
[image]

1st Export action:

[image]

2nd Export action 
[image]

In my research i have found this: http:// www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/uiscripting/index.html but i am not sure if it will work with the traktor menu, and how?

So the question is: How do i control a non-applescript application like Traktor Pro?

Answer (score 1):

By "non-applescript" I assume you mean that the application simply does not have an AppleScript dictionary.  [Accessibility Inspector](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXTesting/OSXAXTestingApps.html) is quite often the remedy, if not [UI Browser](http://pfiddlesoft.com/index.html) is more advanced.

Approach:

1. Turn on assistive devices (as you discovered in your
   research)
2. Identify the UI elements you require using
   Accessibility Inspector
3. Write your shiny new AppleScript (repeat step #2 if
   required)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, i have tried to use both methods and non of them are working for traktor. I can get it to work with other programs but Traktor just has a big Unknown UI Element that is giving me a hard time. It is not possible to export the history/playlist from menu 1 which would be nice, i have been thinking about the "click at" command but dont know if that would be a good solution. here is a picture of the UI Browser interface http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8351/8258391816_ae15052d4b_c.jpg

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  This is certainly more difficult than I had hoped.  Many applications (iTunes included) don't always play nice; see [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547910/how-to-select-speakers-for-itunes-from-applescript).
I would start with the click at command but first set the main window to a fixed size so that you can control your environment a bit.

Comment: I have been playing around some time with it, and I discovered  that the click at and record solution wont work as you dont want the risk of wrong/random mouse-clicks in dj software. So as of now i am going away from the idea of a live stream and exporting the file in the end. Thanks alot for your help!